# Are GooglePlayServices required to work with GCM?

Tags: android

I've been trying to investigate about this on the internet but the information is either unclear or obsolete. The question is pretty straightforward, does Google Play Services need to be installed on the user device if I want to use Push notifications through GCM? I understand I do need to include GPS libraries as a dependency to develop, but does the user also need the GPS APK on his device?

If so, are there any other alternatives? It seems a little too much to impose this dependency for a pretty basic task such as push notifications.

Answer (score 2):

yes it does, GCM is part of Google Play Services.

alternatives would be to use XMPP but you lose all the benefits of GCM

**Update**

as of yesterday GCM is now [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (Firebase Cloud Messaging), its basically GCM re-branded for some dumb reason but it still requires Google Play Services